# Flash object crashes css layout? (Only firefox, chrome all perfect!)

Tags: html, flash, css

Hey stackoverflow community,

i have a problem with a flash object / embedded ...

**That's the image... So it should be.**

[image: This is correct]
**And so it is with flash object / embedded ...**

[image: This is incorrect]
In reality the "opacity" css wouldnt work with the flash object / embedded.
Also the white div wouldnt be visible.
But if i show you a black div, you wouldnt know what i mean.

**How can i fix this?**

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say that: If you add a jsFiddle or something where the problem is clear then you would help is help you faster. Props on uploading the images as well.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JSduh)
Problem with every embedded object... (Information: The corder should be round ^^ thats the problem for example...) /// **tested firefox:** doesnt work. **tested chrome:** works...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for uploading the fiddle, as you can see I forked it and made it work in both browsers now.

The trick was to add `?wmode=transparent` to the parameters passed on the youtube URL.

[Here's a lot more information on that issue](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/swf-file-ignores-stacking-order.html)

And Here is the solution to your issue:

### The Fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/P8rwj/)**

### HTML

```
<iframe width="500" height="500" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0lrrUwyTw2c?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="cover"></div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.cover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #767676;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Please note that I cleaned the code up a bit and made things a bit more readable.

### EDIT

I made a new fiddle with a button that lets you change from the string that says `wmode=gpu` to `wmode=transparent` on the fly.

Please note that I added jquery and this it's currently rigged to be executed on the click of the button... you can certainly implement this in any other way that makes sense for your project

### [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/DmHwD/)

Comment: Thank you. But is there a solution without wmode changes?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, why is this solution not viable for you?

Comment: Because youtube is a example, the object i would modify per Greasemonkey is a game. I would overlay a chat there...
The game requires "wmode=gpu" at start else failed to start.
Maybe i can change the wmode after start, but with firebug i find no solution ...

Comment: Bummer, I see what you mean now. Have you looked at this resource https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swfobject/lfvBH14tdoo where they are talking about changing the wmode on the fly with JS?

Comment: I tested some things with Firebug and the Console. But if i change the url, for example, the object reloads.
If i change parameter: Reloads....

Why chrome has no problem with wmode? Is there a Firefox plugin to handle Flash objects like Chrome? ...

I google since a hour, no solutions for Firefox =.=

Comment: Hey @PatrickKaiser I added a new fiddle on my answer all the way to the bottom. In this fiddle I'm using jquery and regular JS to replace the string that is setting the `wmode` from gpu to transparent on the fly.